# In c++, how to define a template class' nested class constructor, that takes a sibling class for parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, nested

Given example `DirectedGraph`:

What is the definition of the two nested class' constructors?  Based on my observation below, I am guessing it has to do with the constructor's parameters being a sibling class.

`DirectedGraph.tpp`

```
template < class Key,
           class Compare   = std::less<Key>,
           class Allocator = std::allocator<Key> >
class DirectedGraph
{
public:
    // only used for returns/queries
    class Edge
    {
    public:
        Edge(Vertex&, 
             Vertex&);

    private:
        Vertex& from;
        Vertex& to;
    };


    class Vertex
    {
    public:
        Vertex(Key&);
        ~Vertex(void);

    private:
        value T&;
        std::set<Vertex *> edges;
    };

    DirectedGraph(void);
    ~DirectedGraph(void);

    <...lots of methods...>

private:
    size_t num_edges;
    std::set<DirectedGraph<Key, Compare, Allocator>::Vertex *> vertices;
};
```

Visual Studio give me an error (`E0147` declaration is incompatible with "`DirectedGraph<Key, Compare, Allocator>::Edge::Edge(<error-type> &, <error-type> &)`" )

`DirectedGraph.cpp`

```
template <class Key, class Compare, class Allocator>
DirectedGraph<Key, Compare, Allocator>::Edge::Edge
(
    Vertex& from,
    Vertex& to
)
{

}
```

but curiously, not with the Vertex constructor:

```
template<class Key, class Compare, class Allocator>
DirectedGraph<Key, Compare, Allocator>::Vertex::Vertex
(
    Key& value
)
{

}
```

I am guessing this has to do with the latter *not* requiring its sibling nested class as a constructor parameter?

Thanks in advance, I am completely stumped.

### Edit #1

**Forward declaring** (or changing position) as per [quimby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7691729/quimby)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408732/in-c-how-to-define-a-template-class-nested-class-constructor-that-takes-a-s?noredirect=1#comment134734626_76408732) or [user7860670](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/user7860670)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408732/in-c-how-to-define-a-template-class-nested-class-constructor-that-takes-a-s?noredirect=1#comment134734668_76408732) did the trick for the errors.  With a few more tweaks, went from 168 errors to 1.

`DirectedGraph.tpp`

```
template < class Key,
           class Compare   = std::less<Key>,
           class Allocator = std::allocator<Key> >
class DirectedGraph
{
public:
    // only used for returns/queries
    class Edge;
    class Vertex;

    class Edge
    {
    ... everything else identical to above
}
```

`DirectedGraph.cpp`

```
template<class Key, class Compare, class Allocator>
DirectedGraph<Key, Compare, Allocator>::Vertex::Vertex
(
    Key& value
)
{

}

template <class Key, class Compare, class Allocator>
DirectedGraph<Key, Compare, Allocator>::Edge::Edge
(
    Vertex& from,
    Vertex& to
)
{

}
```

Comment: Try moving `Vertex` class definition above `Edge`. If you want help, post a [mcve] - this includes the errors you are getting.

Comment: You should add a forward declaration prior to `Edge` definition `class Vertex;` Or just rearrange `Edge` and `Vertex`.

Comment: ***Visual Studio give me an error with*** What error?  At StackOverflow you need to always show the text of the error message as text. For this code I expect linker errors unless you use explicit intimidations because you implemented your templates in a cpp file. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: ***explicit intimidations*** Oops, looks like auto correct got me.. Should have been explicit instantiations.

Comment: @Quimby worked like a charm! thank you so much.  it seems so obvious now! but i tried every possible permutation of DirectedGraph<>, typename, etc.

Comment: @user7860670 yours would have worked as well, thank you so much

Comment: @drescherjm edited post to include this

Comment: Down from 168 errors to 1!  One last question: for the DirectedGraph constructor... how would one initialize a STL `set` of type `Vertex *`?
`this->vertices = new std::set<Vertex *>();` gets me:
"`C2679` _binary_ '=': _no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type_ `'std::set<DirectedGraph<int,std::less<int>,std::allocator<int>>::Vertex *,std::less<DirectedGraph<int,std::less<int>,std::allocator<int>>::Vertex *>,std::allocator<DirectedGraph<int,std::less<int>,std::allocator<int>>::Vertex *>> *'` (or there is no acceptable conversion)"